# Attempt to call the same function twice passing different arguments

Tags: lua

-- In my main function I do the following calls:

```
function Main()
    FBIVVoit(1,9,1,0)  
    FBIVVoit(1,9,1,1)
end
```

-- This is the function code:

```
function FBIVVoit(numTrain, numCar, numFBIVVoit, State)
  numTrainCount = 1
    while numTrainCount <= numTrain do
      numCarCount = 1
      while numCarCount <= numCar do
        FBIVVoit = dictionary.getvalue(Dict, 'SCVSStatutsV' .. numCarCount .. '.FBIVVoit')
        print('SCVSStatutsV' .. numCarCount .. '.FBIVVoit'
          .. ' before the change is: ' .. FBIVVoit)
        f:write(string.format('\n' .. os.date() .. ' -- ' .. 'SCVSStatutsV'
          .. numCarCount .. '.FBIVVoit' .. ' before the change is: ' .. FBIVVoit))
        dictionary.setvalue(Dict, 'SCVSStatutsV' .. numCarCount .. '.FBIVVoit', State);
        FBIVVoit = dictionary.getvalue(Dict, 'SCVSStatutsV' .. numCarCount .. '.FBIVVoit')
        print('SCVSStatutsV' .. numCarCount .. '.FBIVVoit' .. ' is now: ' .. FBIVVoit)
        f:write(string.format('\n' .. os.date() .. ' -- ' .. 'SCVSStatutsV'
          .. numCarCount .. '.FBIVVoit' .. ' is now: ' .. FBIVVoit))
        fSleep(1)
        numCarCount = numCarCount + 1
      end
      numTrainCount = numTrainCount + 1
    end
    print('Run stopped at ' .. os.date());
    f:write(string.format('\n' .. os.date() .. ' -- ' .. 'Run stopped'))
    f:close()
  end
```

-- When I run the Main, the first call to the FBIVTrain function goes through without a problem. at the second call I get the following error message:

> **error in LUA script: c:\lua\pstm_test.lua:95: attempt to call global 'FBIVVoit' (a number value).**

-- What really bugs me is that I have many other functions I call more than once in a row with different arguments passed to the function and I do not get this behavior.

-- Anyone of you ever experience that or see something wrong looking at my code? Any help would be welcomed as I am stuck there.

Answer (score 4):

You overwrite the function here:

```
FBIVVoit = dictionary.getvalue(Dict, 'SCVSStatutsV' .. numCarCount .. '.FBIVVoit')
```

With the result of `dictionary.getvalue()`. So next time you try to call your function, it's not there anymore.

If you really want to use the same variable name inside the function, use `local` specifier. In fact, **always** use `local` for temporary variables. It's both much faster and doesn't pollute global namespace.